# Partial Differential Equation Auxiliary Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The auxiliary equation of ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients corresponding to $(x^2D^2+xD+1)y=\sin(2\log x)\sin(\log x)$ is ?

I was trying to derive the answer for more than an hour but please help me to get the solution to this problem Thankyou in advance

The question is about auxiliary equation then my doubt is by using Euler-Cauchy's form, I got $((D')^2+1)=0$ but is this correct or $((D')^2-1)=$some other value?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: the question is about auxiliary equation then my doubt is by using euler-cauchy's form, i got ((D')^2+1)=0 but is this correct or ((D')^2-1)=Some other Value?

Comment: Please write all that information, what have you tried etc. Also check [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/867073)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The equation can be written as $x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=\sin[2\log(x)]\sin[\log(x)].$ Let $y(x)=z[\log(x)],$ hence $xy'(x)=z'[\log(x)]$ and $x^2y''(x)=z''[\log(x)]-z'[\log(x)].$ Therefore, $z''[\log(x)]-z'[\log(x)]+z'[\log(x)]+z[\log(x)]=z''[\log(x)]+z[\log(x)]=\sin[2\log(x)]\sin[\log(x)],$ which implies $z''(x)+z(x)=\sin(2x)\sin(x).$ You can solve this equation for $z$, and then solve it for $y$ by noting that $y(x)=z[\log(x)].$ The former is much simpler to solve.